# Visual Studio 2017 Diagnostic tools does not clean up log files

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging, diagnostic-tools

When I run visual studio diagnostic tools it saves the reports to disk automatically. This results in about ~4mb/minute of storage into my temp folder as Report.GUID

When I exit the debugging session these files are not cleaned up. Over a few days of development I end up with gigabytes of diagnostic reports in my temp folder.

I can easily delete these manually however how can I tell diagnostic tools to automatically clean these up or not even create them in the first place? If I set the limit low it simply won't run at all.

I do not want the logs to be persistent, I want them stored in memory and deleted when I stop debugging.

Here are the only options available. If I set disk usage to 1% it still can use up to 1% every time it is run and will not clean up afterwards.

[image]

Comment: Not find settings in VS IDE could clean up them automatically, but I'm think that whether you want to clean the temp folder directly in your windows or others without using the VS IDE.

Comment: Yeah very easy to script I just would like to fix it properly. It seems like a bug to me as no one is going to go look in the temp. Folder

Comment: What about this issue? Would you please share the latest information about it?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for that no VS settings could delete them automatically.

Just provide the workaround I could get.

Create the bat file which could delete the temp files you want to in your windows, and set it as the startup item in your window.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TV7_H2lnklo

Or use certain clean temp tools in your windows.

Of course, if it is convenient, delete them manually would not spend long time:)

I think create the bat script would be a nice workaround for it.

If you really want to get this feature, I also could help you submit this feature to the Visual Studio product team. But you know that it would require enough votes before product team think about adding this feature:)